# Formatting a text to Fit in any shape in SVG

Tags: jquery, d3.js, canvas

How can I use SVG to format a word or small text in any shape for example the attached circle image ?

[Circle Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee08f.png)

I am using following code but the following code is cropping the text not formatting the text. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sukhpalwgt/wzht052c/3/)

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
        text {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 41px
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- <path id="myPath" d="M10 80 C 50 10, 150 10, 190 80 S 330 150, 370 80" fill="transparent" stroke="black" /> -->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <clippath id="triangle1">
                <polygon points="10,30 180,60 250,10" />
            </clippath>
        </defs>
        <polygon points="10,30 180,60 250,10" fill="none" stroke="black" />
        <text x="20" y="50" clip-path="url(#triangle1)" >
            TextExample
        </text>
    </svg>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe it helps: https://gist.github.com/jebeck/196406a3486985d2b92e

Comment: I guess you rather need a sort of [envelope distortion like this](https://pavellaptev.github.io/warp-svg/). It is based on [warp.js](https://benjamminf.github.io/warpjs/). Quite likely, you need to convert your text first to paths via a lib like opentype.js. Frankly, it's rather complicated to achieve this in JS - graphic apps are more capable in this respect.

Comment: @herrstrietzel you are playing with SVG image but i want to create the image from text in svg format.. Means I am putting text in textbox and selecting shape to fit into. For example https://jsfiddle.net/david7418/xvpzcbhp/
Now I want to convert above canvas into svg image.